# Return (send) int with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If I do this with Express it fails:

```
res.send(13245)
```

It says:

> express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead src/x.js:38:9
>   (node:25549) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 13245

It's because it consider `13245` might be a status code.
I want to return `13245` anyway, is there a way do do this?

Comment: Did you try `res.status(200).send(13245)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return a String (see http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send):

```
res.send('13245')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check documentation http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send, the value just can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array. What if you send

```
res.send({ value: 13245 })
```

and then in the other side you just need to grab the value (e.g. body.value).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `res.send('13245');` or you can try `res.send(""+13245)`.

You are getting that error because Express assumes you are trying to send a status code. So you can send it as a string and Express will accept it or join it to a string and Express should think you are sending back just some plain number and yes always check the docs when you run into trouble:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

Answer (score 0):

let say you are doing a calculation and you wanna send the result.

```
app.post("/transaction", (req, res) => {
  const a = req.body.amount;
  const b = req.body.price;
  const total = a*b;
  res.send(total.toString());
});
```