# How to pass data from Node.js to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to get data from Node.js in my javascript as part of a task.

The node.js

```
app.get('',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index.ejs')
})
app.get('/calculateResult',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(id)
    res.send(5)
})
```

The javascript file is a linked script in the index.ejs.

The js

```
const pullLever = async function(){
    let response = await fetch('/calculateResult')
    alert(JSON.stringify(response,null,4))
}
```

I expect five(5) to be contained in the alert response whenever the 'pullLever' function is called, but with this code the response is just an empty dictionary({}), any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `JSON.stringify(response,null,4)` returns {} because `response` is not return response body, but [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. if what you want is get the response body, you should [`Response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) it (or [`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) it).

```js
const pullLever = async function() {
    const response = await fetch('/calculateResult');
    const text = await response.text();
    alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}
```

or

```js
const response = await fetch('/calculateResult').then((val) => val.text());
```

and why does Response object can't be stringified? Response's fields is [private](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields). *I guess*.

Answer (score 1):

For your nodejs, your using `res.send` with int. Please read this answer: [how to send int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609239/return-send-int-with-express-js)

For nodejs, you would have something like:

```js
"use strict";
app.get('/calculateResult', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({myNumber: 5});
    // or res.send('5');
});
```

And in your file:

```js
// Edit: This would be your lever function.
(async () => {
      let res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:4000/calculateResult");
      res.json().then(function(data) {
         console.log(data); // Check console for output
      });
})();
```

Edit: Tested, your output for when you `alert` should be `[object object]` and `5` for the commented out line `res.send('5')`; If your not using `nodemon` or similar, don't forget to restart your server after changes.