# Express: unable to send a number to the client

Tags: node.js, express, numbers, send

I have to expose a number as plain text, in according with `res.send([1,2,3])` as described here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send 
I thought it was easy to do this:

```
res.send(1000);
```

but...

> RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 1000

wait, HTTP STATUS CODE 1000?! how is it possible?

...let me try again with more brain:

```
res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain')
   .status(200)
   .send(1000)
   .end();
```

error again:

> RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 1000

so, let me try another attempt

```
res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain')
   .status(200)
   .send('1000')
   .end();
```

It works! but.. I have no a string, i have a number! so i want to send it as as number!

...and many many attempts later... a very bad solution:

```
res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain')
   .json(1000)
   .end();
```

It also works, but not approved due to https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

so, the last one:

```
res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain')
   .send(JSON.stringify(1000))
   .end();
```

ok, but i believe it is better casting into a string instead of a json

so, what's wrong in `.send(<number>)` ?

how to send a number to the client without casting?

and how to send a plain number to the client without any cast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609239/return-send-int-with-express-js